# How to add an 'AS' alias in a PIVOT command with dynamic columns?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to add an 'AS' alias in a PIVOT command with dynamic columns? I was unsure if it would be possible. If it is, I have provided a simple example below.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Sales
GO

CREATE TABLE #Sales
(
    [Product] VARCHAR(50),
    [Month]   INT,
    [Revenue] MONEY
)
GO

INSERT INTO #Sales
VALUES ('Product A', 1, 1000),
       ('Product A', 2, 1500),
       ('Product B', 1, 2000),
       ('Product B', 3, 2500),
       ('Product C', 2, 3000),
       ('Product C', 3, 3500),
       ('Product D', 4, 999)
GO


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Month])
                      FROM #Sales
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')


SET @query = '

SELECT [Product]
     , ' + @cols + '
FROM (SELECT [Product]
           , [Month]
           , [Revenue]
      FROM #Sales) x
         PIVOT
         (
         SUM([Revenue])
         FOR [Month] IN (' + @cols + ')
         ) p

'

EXECUTE (@query)
```

I don't know how many months will be returned, but the goal is to alias the columns corresponding to the months.

```
Product     |JAN        |FEB        |MAR        |APR
---------------------------------------------------------
Product A   |1000.0000  |1500.0000  |NULL       |
Product B   |2000.0000  |NULL       |2500.0000  |
Product C   |NULL       |3000.0000  |3500.0000  |
Product D   |NULL       |NULL       |NULL       |999.0000
```

Comment: Perhaps consider that this task is better suited for your presentation layer, not the SQL layer.

Comment: You'll need another variable to inject into your dynamic sql which is similar to @cols but with `AS ColumnName` for each column as well. (Where ColumnName is the alias you'd like the column to have)

Comment: Replace the [X] in  @cols with [X] AS MON for the select part of @query.. `SET @query = '

SELECT [Product]
     , ' + 
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@cols, 
  '[1]', '[1] AS JAN'),
  '[2]', '[2] AS FEB'), 
  '[3]', '[3] AS MAR'),
  '[4]', '[4] AS APR'),
  '[5]', '[5] AS MAY'),
  '[6]', '[6] AS JUN'),
  '[12]', '[12] AS DEC')
  + '
FROM (SELECT [Product]…`

Comment: Given the limited number of months in a year why not just cross apply a mapping table that converts the month numbers 1..12 to JAN..DEC and use those month names in @Cols?

Comment: Agreed, I would strongly advise a static query for a fixed 12 months.

Answer (score 0):

For the given example, the simplest way to solve this would be.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Sales
GO

CREATE TABLE #Sales
(
    [Product] VARCHAR(50),
    [Month]   INT,
    [Revenue] MONEY
)
GO

INSERT INTO #Sales
VALUES ('Product A', 1, 1000),
       ('Product A', 2, 1500),
       ('Product B', 1, 2000),
       ('Product B', 3, 2500),
       ('Product C', 2, 3000),
       ('Product C', 3, 3500),
       ('Product D', 4, 999)
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #MonthNames
CREATE TABLE #MonthNames
(
    [Month] INT,
    [MonthName] VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #MonthNames
VALUES (1, 'Jan'),
       (2, 'Fev'),
       (3, 'Mar'),
       (4, 'Abr'),
       (5, 'Mai'),
       (6, 'Jun'),
       (7, 'Jul'),
       (8, 'Ago'),
       (9, 'Set'),
       (10, 'Out'),
       (11, 'Nov'),
       (12, 'Dez')

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @cols_with_alias AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Month])
                      FROM #Sales
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

-- Creating the new variable with the custom aliases
SELECT @cols_with_alias = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + QUOTENAME(m.[Month]) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(m.[MonthName])
                      FROM #Sales s
                      JOIN #MonthNames m ON s.[Month] = m.[Month]
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

SET @query = '

SELECT [Product]
     , ' + @cols_with_alias + '
FROM (SELECT [Product]
           , [Month]
           , [Revenue]
      FROM #Sales) x
         PIVOT
         (
         SUM([Revenue])
         FOR [Month] IN (' + @cols + ')
         ) p

'

EXECUTE (@query)
```